# WKWebKit on iOS crashes without debug information

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit, mobile-webkit

WebKit is crashing on iOS 11 without any debugging information - below is the best I can do.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
```

Is it possible to find out why this is crashing?

Thanks

```
WebKit`>::lookup<WTF::HashMapTranslatorAdapter<WTF::HashMap<WTF::String, WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebURLSchemeHandler>, WTF::StringHash, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::String>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebURLSchemeHandler> > >::KeyValuePairTraits, WTF::IdentityHashTranslator<WTF::HashMap<WTF::String, WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebURLSchemeHandler>, WTF::StringHash, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::String>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebURLSchemeHandler> > >::KeyValuePairTraits, WTF::StringHash> >, WTF::String>:
    0x19270161c <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-0x50]!
    0x192701620 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x10]
    0x192701624 <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x20]
    0x192701628 <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x30]
    0x19270162c <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x40]
    0x192701630 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #0x40            ; =0x40 
    0x192701634 <+24>:  mov    x19, x1
    0x192701638 <+28>:  ldr    w21, [x0, #0xc]
    0x19270163c <+32>:  ldr    x22, [x0]
    0x192701640 <+36>:  ldr    x0, [x19]
->  0x192701644 <+40>:  ldr    w8, [x0, #0x10]
```

Comment: How are you creating WKWebView? by code or storyboard?

Comment: I'm creating the WKWebView through code.

Comment: I have the same exact crash as well...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url you are using has the http url scheme using the following code:

```
if !urlString.hasPrefix("http://") && !urlString.hasPrefix("https://")
    {
        urlString = "http://" + urlString
    }
```

You may also need to ensure you have NSAllowsArbitraryLoads enabled, open your plist as source code and copy and past this in.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```